Html/css flex: Preventing element from overflowing browser window
I'm trying to make a segment of a webpage where an image will appear on the left or right and directly next to it there can be text centered on its segment of the page (see image).
However, the element holding the text is wider than the available space for it because its defaulting to the width of the entire page despite being slightly to the right, causing the text to be off-center.
Is there a way to account for the variable width of the image without this overflow?
Here are the HTML and CSS snippets for the elements I'm using and a photo of the issue:


.row {
    display: flex;
    flex:0 0 100%;
    max-height:80%;
    width:100%;
}

.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex:0 0 100%;
    justify-items: center;
    max-height:50%;
    width:100%;
    
}

img {
    display:flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    object-fit: contain;
}
<div class="row" style="max-height: 80%">
    <img src="./images/garden-state.webp">

    <div class="column" style="width:min-content;">
        <div class="title" style="background-color: #1b1b1b; max-height: 30%;"><h3>Garden State</h3></div>
    </div>
</div>




Ideally the text should be horizontally centered in the visible portion of the header element. I've tried multiple different values for the width variable, from different percentages to min-content and the such with nothing changing at all.
Any help is appreciated!

CSS Code
.row {
    display: flex;
    max-height:80%;
    width:100%;
}
.column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center; 
    align-items: center;
    width:100vw;
    background-color: #1b1b1b;
}

img {
    display:flex;
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    object-fit: contain;
}

HTML Code
<div class="row" style="max-height: 80%">
    <img src="image.jpeg"> <!--Add image-->

    <div class="column">
        <div class="title" style="color: white; "><h3>Garden State</h3></div>
    </div>
</div>

Try out this code...
Upvote if this was helpful :)

You sir are a saint thank you
Only issue is that position: absolute on the image caused it to overflow way too large, but leaving that change out its exactly how i was aiming for

You're welcome. Happy to help :)

If you are just looking to center the text in h3. You can just add h3 {text-align: center}. It should center the text to available width.
However, if you want to remove the extra bit of unnecessary horizontal scroll.
You can try something like this, where you remove the set width and hide the overflow so the width will be set automatically. You can take a look at this for example. Codepen_Example
.row {
  overflow: hidden; 
}


The horizontal scrolling is because you changed flex-shrink to "0" via the shorthand declaration flex:0 0 100%;, preventing the container from shrinking to fit the available space. The flex declaration is not even needed.


.row {
  display: flex;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.title {
  color: white;
  background-color: #1b1b1b;
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 50%;
}
<div class="row">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/wiKmgQpY.jpg">

    <div class="column">
        <div class="title"><h3>Garden State</h3></div>
    </div>
</div>



